# convert yyyymmdd hh24miss to dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss

Tags: scala, apache-spark, date

I have loaded data to Scala Dataframe and I have a field which of type `String` in this format `"20201208140823"`, as you can see it is date and time.

The question how can I  convert it to date in this format `dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss`. I tried and search the web and I could not find the appropriate function and answer. Can anyone help ?

`last_edit` is the field

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val DF_MelbParkBayInfo = spark.sql("select the_geom,marker_id,meter_id,bay_id,  last_edit ,  rd_seg_id,rd_seg_dsc from temp_MelbParkBayInfo")

DF_MelbParkBayInfo:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
the_geom:string
marker_id:string
meter_id:string
bay_id:string
last_edit:string
rd_seg_id:string
rd_seg_dsc:string
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? What is blocking you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have built-in functions to achieve the required result in spark:

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  
  // Sample dataframe   
  val df = Seq("20201208140823","20211210140823").toDF("last_edit")

  // Method#1
  df.withColumn("last_edit",
    date_format(to_timestamp('last_edit,"yyyyMMddHHmmss"),"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
    .show()
  // Method#2
  df.withColumn("last_edit", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('last_edit,"yyyyMMddHHmmss"),"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
    .show()

+-------------------+
|          last_edit|
+-------------------+
|08-12-2020 14:08:23|
|10-12-2021 14:08:23|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried this solution and it works fine I used method#1

import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
val DF_MelbParkBayInfo_DATED = DF_MelbParkBayInfo.withColumn("last_edit",
    date_format(to_timestamp('last_edit,"yyyyMMddHHmmss"),"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"))
DF_MelbParkBayInfo_DATED.printSchema()
DF_MelbParkBayInfo_DATED.show()

But last_edit still of type String, I tried to use To_date to convert it or cast(DateType), but it did not work. How can I change the datetype to date?

Comment: Spark's default date-time format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. If we are converting any other format to this default format using cast/to_date/to_timestamp methods then only we can get date/timestamp type. E.g -->  df.withColumn("last_edit",to_timestamp('last_edit,"yyyyMMddHHmmss")).printSchema().

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it in Java and I believe you should be able to use/adapt it in Scala.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "20201208140823";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfInput);
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Formatted
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtfOutput.format(ldt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-08T14:08:23
08-12-2020 14:08:23
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Xsmgq8)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.